# How to apply master font and color to existing slides in LibreOffice Impress

Tags: usability, presentation, libreoffice

I created a master/template in Impress by selecting:

1. `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Colors` to select colors for creating a new gradient
2. `Format > Area : Gradients` to create the gradient using the selected colors
3. `View > Master > Slide Master` in order to edit the slide master
4. `Format > Page` to set the page background to that gradient
5. Finally saved the file as template in `/.libreoffice/3/user/template`

I then opened an existing presentation and selected:

1. `Format > Slide Design : Load` and added my template
2. `Task pane: Master Pages ...` right-clicked on my template to select `Apply To All Slides`

The template gets applied somehow, but fonts and font colors are not applied to the existing slides.

How does this work please? 
Or, is there a bug filed for this somewhere? Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the template-based formatting should work, i've tried it with LibreOffice 3.4.3. Without any **direct formatting** (using the `text formatting` toolbar or right-click and select any of the formatting options), the new template is applied globally. But if there's any **direct formatting**, the new template's formatting rules **won't affect that content**.

If the new template isn't applied to some slides, you should check if there's any **direct formatting** defined for those slides, and remove it using Menu `Format` -> `Default Formatting`.

Answer (score 0):

After you have applying the new style to the old presentation, you must go in each slide and select the appropriate layout. It will set the formats and fonts of the style of the master slide. It may mess-up some graphics. IN these cases right-click the graphic and click "original size". 
Jorge